# MySQL Combine Query and ignore duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables **images2** and **image_data**

[image]
[image]

So the goal is to have 1 table for ALL the image uploads (images2) and then the image_data is to assign that image with different options.

So for example, here is some sample data:

[image]

So image_id 10 has more than one row, because this image is associated with both TN and CQ.  And they could also be associated with more than one language and slide, so I would add on to the second row and change slide_id or language_id .. if wanted to add more, than I would add a new row for it.

The goal is to have a list of all the images, and then when you click on it it pops up and you can edit the options and change it straight from there.

[image]

I need help writing a query.  The one I have right now:

```
SELECT images2.id, images2.filename, image_data.slide_id, image_data.language_id,
image_data.type FROM images2 
LEFT JOIN image_data ON images2.id = image_data.image_id
```

A couple things wrong with that query..  It is showing the duplicates, because image_id 10 has two rows.

[image]

But I need that second row of image #10 because I need to see that it is also associated with CQ so I can check the checkbox when it pops up.

So I need to create a query to show ALL the unique images no duplicates, with all of the options it has.

I'm not sure the best way to do this.. do I need to re-do the way my database tables are? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by " show ALL the unique images no duplicates, with all of the options it has" best to show the expected output

Comment: I am using one query to show all the images and to grab all of the options.  so if my query returns multiple rows of the same photo_id, my photo gallery will show that image more than once.

Comment: but you said  I need to see that it is also associated with CQ as well - so exactly what do you want?

Comment: I don't think `group_concat` is going to do it for you because when displaying your form you'll probably need the ID's for each slide/language/etc.  Couldn't you just use PHP to make sure you aren't displaying the same photo twice...then when showing the details you'll have all the needed information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to turn values in multiple rows into a single concatenated string. The following retrieves the ids of `slides` and `languages` as well as their names to better facilitate your form.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.filename,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.slide_id, '::', c.slide_name)) AS slides,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.language_id, '::', d.language_name)) AS languages,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.type) AS types,
FROM 
    images a
LEFT JOIN
    image_data b ON a.id = b.image_id
LEFT JOIN 
    slides c ON b.slide_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN
    languages d ON c.language_id = d.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

Your result set for image `10` will look something like:

```
id    |    image_filename    |    slides    |    languages    |    types
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
10    |    p170sfhe...       |    5::slide5 |    1::language1 |    TN,CQ
```

In php, just `explode()` the strings based on the delimiters.

Comment: except the space in "TN, CQ", as the default separator is ',' without space, so its only "TN,CQ"

Answer (score 1):

you could use GROUP_CONCAT to get a csv of the fields:

```
SELECT
  images2.id,
  images2.filename,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image_data.slide_id) AS slides,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image_data.language_id) AS langs,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT image_data.type) AS types
FROM images2 
LEFT JOIN image_data ON (images2.id = image_data.image_id)
GROUP BY images2.id
```